# How to set searchView to left side with setTransition or setX?

Tags: android-layout, android-actionbar, android-xml, searchview

When I place searchView.setX or searchView.setTranslation it only allows me to use a positive number. Never a negative number. I can't even move the searchView to left with searchView.setX(1/1000) for example.   Why can't I move searchView to left side with setX or setTransition yet I can move it to right side?

This is how it looks as searchView.setX(100);

(as you see in pic the searchView icon moved to right side and is overlapping the settings button)
[image]

I used the following code to add the searchView in my onCreateOptionsMenu method

```
   MenuItem item= menu.findItem(menuSearch);                        
   final SearchView searchView = (SearchView) item.getActionView();
```

I know I can create a custom searchView instead like with the following...

```
final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
assert actionBar != null;
actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
actionBar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_search);
```

...but I already have code set up for all types of actions with the menu_main.xml menuSearch.

How do I move searchView to left side with using my menu_main.xml searchView and setX or setTranslation or is there another code? Or do I just add something in menu_main.xml?